# vim c auto complete in insert mode WITHOUT pressing C-X C-O

Tags: c, vim

My vim (version 7.3) goes into a strange situation with c codes:

When it goes into insert mode, after I press a key, `s` for example, then vim will give me all keywords in tag file (a file generated by ctags -R):

```
strstrip(
sample_check(
sabd
...
```

Just like I pressed C-X C-O, but I didn't, I just only pressed `s`

Then, press another key `p` for example, then intelligently autocomplete again:

```
sp_print(
sp_test(
...
```

I forgot how i got into this mode, anyone could help me?

Comment: Well, did you look for an autocompletion plugin in your `~/.vim` directory?

Comment: actually,i'm wondering how did it happen

Comment: It happened because you've made it happen: 1. by downloading and installing an autocompletion plugin [and 2. by activating it, if the plugin needs activation]. Hence my question: *did you look for an autocompletion plugin in your ~/.vim directory?*

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this plugin: [AutoComplPop](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1879)

Comment: sorry,maybe i didn't describe my problem clearly,i just want to know how did this strange thing happen

Comment: Oh! My bad. Didn't understand your question.